# SAP HANA How to debug / fix "insufficient privilege" Error

Tags: permissions, hana

In SAP HANA I am trying to call a StoredProcedure with a Table Type as input parameter.

Other Input parameters work just fine. But as soon as I use a Table Type I get the error:

`Failed to execute action: InternalError: dberror($.hdb.Connection.executeProcedure): 258 - SQL error, server error code: 258. insufficient privilege: Not authorized at /sapmnt/ld7272/a/HDB/jenkins_prod/workspace/8uyiojyvla/s/ptime/query/checker/query_check.cc:4003`

How to fix / debug this?

In the indexserver-trace is:

```
[19984]{315590}[100/100235487] 2018-08-22 10:07:13.949679 i TraceContext     TraceContext.cpp(01028) : UserName=SAPDBCTRL, ApplicationUserName=SM_EFWK, ApplicationName=ABAP:AS2, ApplicationSource=CL_SQL_STATEMENT==============CP:304, Client=010, StatementHash=31c1e1f5ca72868a541d58fc5a77596b, EppRootContextId=0050560204981EE782C14A33A16BC68E, EppTransactionId=47BF1E2CEE9D05A0E005B7CF04FCF981, EppConnectionId=5B7C13CC22061B08E10000000A1807AF, EppConnectionCounter=1, EppComponentName=AS2/sapas2ci_AS2_01, EppAction=EFWK RESOURCE MANAGER
[19984]{315590}[100/100235487] 2018-08-22 10:07:13.949656 w SQLScriptExecuto se_eapi_proxy.cc(00144) : Error <exception 71000258: Not authorized
> in preparation of internal statement: delete from _SYS_STATISTICS.STATISTICS_PROPERTIES where key='internal.check.store_results'
[19984]{315590}[100/100235487] 2018-08-22 10:07:13.949904 e SQLScript        trex_llvm.cc(00936) : Llang Runtime Error: Exception::SQLException258: insufficient privilege: Not authorized
  at main (line 63) ("_SYS_STATISTICS"."SHARED_STORE_USED_VALUES": line 8 col 5 (at pos 456))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather straightforward:

The **application user** (the person using SAP NetWeaver) `SM_EFWK` logged on in client `010` is trying to delete data from an SAP HANA statistics service table `_SYS_STATISTICS.STATISTICS_PROPERTIES`.

The NetWeaver/ABAP program uses a **secondary database** connection with the database user `SAPDBCTRL`.
The error `Exception::SQLException258: insufficient privilege: Not authorized` is thrown, because this `SAPDBCTRL` database user, does not have the privilege to `DELETE` on this table assigned to it (neither directly, nor via schema or role privilege).

If the SQL command is part of an SAP standard program, then I'd check that the recommended setup has been implemented correctly. 
If this command comes from a custom program, you may want to either assign the privilege or use a different technical user as `SAPDBCTRL` is an SAP standard user that shouldn't be modified.